# How to log to a file from a dockerized php app

Tags: php, docker, error-logging

I have a php app dockerized.
My issue is how to capture errors from php service into a dedicated file on the host.
docker file looks is next:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./public:/public
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PHP.Dockerfile
    environment:
      APP_MODE: 'development'
    env_file:
      - 'dev.env'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./public:/public
      - ./php.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-log.conf
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <pass here>
    env_file:
      - 'dev.env'
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
        - '3306:3306'
volumes:
  mysqldata: {}
```

my `php.conf` that maps as `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-log.conf` inside php service looks like bellow:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /app/php-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
catch_workers_output = yes
```

My intention is using php `error_log()` function and have all the logs recorded in `php-error.log` which is a file inside volume `app`.
Now, all logs from containers are shown on terminal only.

I have been struggling with this several hours and have no ideea how to continue. Thank you

Comment: Can you give us some more information like what is or isn't working? Are you able to log to the file at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your source image. I assume some official docker image for PHP like https://hub.docker.com/_/php

All containerized applications are usually configured to log to `stdout` so you must override that behaviour. This is really PHP specific and I'm no PHP expert. From what you let us know it looks like you know how to override that behaviour (by using some `error_log()` function and `php_admin_value[error_log] = /app/php-error.log` property.

If the behaviour is overridden you should ensure the file `app/php-error.log` exists inside of the PHP container (i.e. get inside the container by something like `docker exec -it my-container-id /bin/bash` and then do `ls /app/php-error.log` and `cat /app/php-error.log` to see if the file is created.

Because you're mounting the `./app` directory from the host to `/app` directory in container you already have them mirrored. Whatever is inside container's `/app` you will find in also your `/path/to/docker/compose/app` directory. You can check if file exists and some content is inside. If not you failed to override the default behaviour of where PHP is logging to.

Comment: After some time...is done. The container `php' directs errors to stderr `[global]
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2`
so, I overridden directive placing inside 'php-fpm.conf.d' directory a file named 'zz-my.conf'  ```[global]
error_log = /app/php-error.log
 ```